# the name of a game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I saw a two-player game described the other day and I was just wondering if it had an official name.  The game is played as follows: You start with an $m \times n$ grid, and on each node of the grid there is a rock.  On your turn, you point to a rock.  The rock and all other rocks "northeast" of it are removed.  In other words, if you point to the rock at position $(i,j)$ then any rock at position $(r,s)$ where $r$ and $s$ satisfy $1 \leq r \leq i$ and $j \leq s \leq n$ is removed.  The loser is the person who takes the last rock(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This game is called [Chomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp).